# Cycle cover of a cubic polyhedral graph

Tags: graph-theory

Tutte graph is a counterexample for the Tait's conjecture stating that all cubic graphs are Hamiltonian. For the non-hamiltonian graphs - is it true that all vertices of any such graph can be covered by a set of cycles?

Comment: Each vertex is on a cycle, so the answer to your question would be yes. But this is probably not what you mean. Please clarify.

Comment: Tait's conjecture says that every *planar* *3-connected* cubic graph is Hamiltonian. In every at least 2-connected graph, each vertex is on a cycle, and so yes, the graph can be covered with a set of cycles. If you don't restrict to at least 2-connected graphs, there are cubic planar graphs with vertices not participating in any cycles.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "covered by a set of mutually non-overlapping  cycles".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, each cubic polyhedral graph can be covered by a set of mutually disjoint cycles.
This is a trivial consequence of Petersen's theorem that states that every bridgeless, cubic graph has a 1-factor. Since a polyhedral graph is bridgeless, it has a 1-factor.
Removing this 1-factor leaves a regular graph of degree 2, which is a union of disjoint cycles.